# How to handle Nested and Paginated Network Call in Swift Combine

Tags: swift, combine

I'm using the Notion api which returns all the data I need in `Block` objects. The struggle is that each `Block` can be paginated and/or have children that is an array of `Block`.

Basic `Block` Structure:

```
struct Block {
     var id: String
     var data: [Data]
     var hasMore: Bool
     var hasChildren: Bool
     var childrenId: String
     var nextPageId: String
     var children: [Block]? = nil

     // used for pagination to append data
     mutating func accumulator(newRes: BlockResponse) -> BlockResponse {
         let combinedArr = self.results + newRes.results
         var combinedRes = newRes
         combinedRes.results = combinedArr
         self = combinedRes
         return self
     }
}
```

What I am trying to do:

1. Pass in list of `Block` Ids
2. Get all of the `Block` data for each ID including all paginated and nested data

Note:

- The paginated data should be stored in the original `Block` `data` field
- The children data should be stored in their parent `Block` `children` field
- Each child `Block` can also have paginated data and/or children data

I've gotten semi-close, but I just can't figure out how to get the nested and paginated children data (the last function below). I'm sure I am way overcomplicating this, but right now it basically returns everything properly except the nested children data (it only returns 1 level deep).

Current Code

```
func getAllBlockData() -> AnyPublisher<[Block], Never> {     
    return loadAllBlockIds() // just returns a list of ids
        .map { $0.results.map { $0 } } // getting the ids from a list of ids
        .flatMap(\.publisher)
        .flatMap(loadBlockData)
        .collect()
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

func loadBlockData(forId id: String) -> AnyPublisher<Block, Never> {
    return loadBlock(id: id)
        .flatMap(getMoreBlockData)
        .flatMap(getChildData)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()       
}


func loadBlock(forId id: String) -> AnyPublisher<Block, Never> {
    // basic code to get the block data
}


func getMoreBlockData(forBlock block: Block) -> AnyPublisher<Block, Never> {
    if block.hasMore {
        return loadMoreBlockData(forBlock: block)
    }
    
    return Just(block).eraseToAnyPublisher()
}


func getChildData(forBlock block: Block) -> AnyPublisher<Block, Never> {
    if block.hasChildren {
        return loadChildData(forBlock: block)
    }

    return Just(block).eraseToAnyPublisher()
}


// Recursively calls its inner function to accumulate the paginated data
func loadMoreBlockData(forBlock block: Block) -> AnyPublisher<Block, Never> {
    func doRequest(forId id: String, accumulator: Block) -> AnyPublisher<Block, Never> {
        return loadBlock(id: id)
            .flatMap { blockRes -> AnyPublisher<Block, Never> in
                var mutableAccumulator = accumulator
                
                if blockRes.hasMore {
                    return doRequest(forId: blockRes.moreId!, accumulator: mutableAccumulator.accumulator(newRes: blockRes))
                }
                
                return Just(mutableAccumulator.accumulator(newRes: blockRes)).eraseToAnyPublisher()
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    return doRequest(forId: block.moreId!, accumulator: block)
}


// This is causing me the problems (well, at least the major ones)
func loadChildData(forBlock block: Block) -> AnyPublisher<Block, Never> {
    var mutableBlock = block
    func doRequest(forId id: String) -> AnyPublisher<Block, Never> {
        return loadBlock(id: id)
            .flatMap(getMoreBlockData)
            .flatMap({ childRes -> AnyPublisher<Block, Never> in
                if mutableBlock.children != nil {
                    mutableBlock.children?.append(childRes)
                } else {
                    mutableBlock.children = [childRes]
                }

                return Just(childRes).eraseToAnyPublisher()
            })
            .flatMap(getChildData)
            .flatMap { _ -> AnyPublisher<BlockResponse, Never> in
                return Just(mutableBlock).eraseToAnyPublisher()
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    return doRequest(forId: block.childId!)
}
```

Comment: There is no way the code you posted above works. There is no `string` or `bool` type in Swift. Please post a compilable sample of your current code.